# Use a Kotlin jar library in Java project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, kotlin

I have a Java project in Eclipse and I have to use an external jar written in Kotlin.
When a class from tha jar is about to be used I have an error:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics`

I added the Kotlin plugin - it didn't help.
To the project I added libs:

kotlin-stdlib-1.5.20-RC.jar

kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.20.jar

kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.20-RC.jar

kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.20-RC.jar

annotations-13.0.jar

Some time ago I had the following program in Android Studio but there it was enough to add

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.32"
```

in the gradle file. I guess I have to do something similar but I have problems in achieving this :(

[image: buildpath]

Comment: Can you show the `build.gradle`?

Comment: It's not a gradle project. It's just a Java project.

Comment: What build tool do you use? Msven? In that case, show your `pom.xml`. If you don't use a build tool at all but it is a plain eclipse project, show your build path.

Comment: I use Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. It's a Java Project.

Comment: What is your build path, then?

Comment: Please edit your question and upload the image there and do not use google drive. (You didn't even allow access to that file)

Comment: Added the image to to the question.

Answer (score 0):

As I haven't found a solution to this problem I finished with making a Kotlin project in which I just use Java.  It works :)